# Windows 10 kiosk mode : starts desktop application but volume cannot be set

Tags: windows-10, kiosk-mode

On a Windows 10 version 1909 I'm trying to configure a WPF desktop application in kiosk mode but volume setting both from keyboard and from buttons on the monitor is not working which seems to be due to explorer.exe not being started. I'm using Windows Configuration Designer to configure the WPF app to be started in kiosk mode. Before the current WPF app, I had a UWP app that was being configured also using Windows Configuration Designer and everything worked fine (volume setting was working fine).

Based on what I was able to understand, when using Windows Configuration Designer to configure a UWP application in kiosk mode, assigned access is the kiosk configuration method used while when Windows Configuration Designer is used to configure any desktop application it seems that shell launcher v1 (eshell.exe) ends up being the kiosk method used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make volume setting work once more OOB by switching to shell launcher v2 (customshellhost.exe).